# 3D shapes using SVG or WebGL

Tags: javascript, svg, webgl

Hi I want to render an interactive 3D sphere in browser. The texture on it will be of a world map, so basically I am trying to create a globe which is rotatable in any direction using map. I am comfortable in rendering 2D images using SVG but not sure how to render 3D shapes in SVG. 
Is it possible to render a 3D shape in SVG, if yes, how? If not, is WebGl a better option?

Comment: `I want to render an interactive 3D sphere in browser` - which browser?

Comment: you asked for it http://kathack.com/

Comment: @atlavis, any browser which can support the solution.C'mon

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WebGL is your best bet because of performance.  You might be able to leverage (or at least learn from) demos like http://www.chromeexperiments.com/globe (see http://data-arts.appspot.com/globe-search).  There are also other globe demos at http://www.chromeexperiments.com.

Comment: That's the best solution. It requires quite a lot of code and some OpenGL/GLSL/math knowledge though.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) which abstracts the implementation a bit (comes with WebGL/SVG/Canvas backends).

SVG is a 2d vector graphics format, but you can project 3d shapes onto 2d, so it's possible to render 3d objects with SVG, it's just a bit of work (best left to javascript libraries).

Comment: "SVG is a 2d vector graphics format, but you can project 3d shapes onto 2d". I agree but is it possible to make them interactive? can I rotate the 3d sphere which I create in svg?

Comment: Any shape in svg can be interactive, but SVG itself has no clue that certain shapes are representing a 3d object. Here's a simple example (3d cube with mouseover handlers): http://apike.ca/prog_svg_threed.html

Answer (score 4):

If you use SVG then shading is going to be a problem. Proper shading is not really possible in SVG, though you might be able to fake it a few select circumstances. For 3D definitely use WebGL if you have more than a dozen or so polygons in the model.

Comment: This is such a key point that for me it makes webGL not the better solution, but the *only* solution. Even if you manage to hack it together you'll spend much more time making it looks even slightly non-lego-like (not to mention work properly - clipping etc) in svg, than the extra time you'll spend making the webGL match SVG for interactivity.

Comment: @posfan12 I'm looking for help with a question. Searching SO, you are the only person to offer an opinion on shading SVG graphics. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905255/how-to-change-color-of-a-composite-svg-oject

Answer (score 2):

You must transform all point with a projection
USe this to change point2D(x,y) in point3D(x,y,z):

```
  // Language Javascript

  // object Point 

  function Point(x,y,z){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z; 
  }

 // Projection convert point 2D in 3D

  function ProjectionPoint(point){
    if ( !(point instanceof Point) )
    throw new TypeError("ProjectionPoint: incorrect type parameter");

    return { x: (point.x<<8)/(point.z+Zorig)+Xorig, 
             y: (point.y<<8)/(point.z+Zorig)+Yorig, 
             z:point.z  } 
 }
```

Make sure, you have defined your origine point under the variable Xorig, Yorig, Zorig